# Caret color changes to error text color in flutter textformfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

When my flutter `textformfield` throws a validation error, the caret color changes to the same color that I have set in `errorStyle`.

Is there a way to turn this off?

```
TextFormField(
  controller: emailController,
  decoration: getInputDecorationTheme('Email'),
  validator: (value) {
    setState(
      () {
        errorMessage = '';
      },
    );
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter your email';
    }
    if (!_isValidEmail(value)) {
      return 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }
    return null;
  },
),
```

And this is how my decoration looks.

```
InputDecoration getInputDecorationTheme(String hintText) {
    return InputDecoration(
      hintText: hintText,
      hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
      errorStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      ),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: StaticColors.backgroundColor,
      border: const OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
      // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 15),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0, top: 15.0),
      prefix: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is how the caret looks per default (I always want to show this color).

[image: image 1]

Here is how the caret looks when I've triggered a validation error.

[image: image 2]

Tried looking in the decorator to find a settings for this but doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: My suggestion is that instead of using the text form field validation at all, create a text below the form field and manually validate it with a method and show it whenever you want with any color!

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion. The original problem I have is that the caret color changes, not the validation text under the textbox. But perhaps I can just write my own text box altogether. Maybe that's the only solution to this.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `cursorColor: Colors.black` to fix for all states of textformfield.

Comment: Have you tested this? it doesnt work once there's a validation error..

Comment: I'm afraid this suggestion doesn't work.